# Swashbuckle/Swagger - how do I require the apiKey for a certain operation/at per operation level?

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I've installed Swashbuckle in an ASP.NET std project and enabled the options for ApiKey in Swagger and SwaggerUI, with the default config options:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(c =>
  c.ApiKey("whatever")
    .Description("API Key Authentication")
    .Name("apiKey")
    .In("header")
).EnableSwaggerUI(c => c.EnableApiKeySupport("apiKey", "header"));
```

The option to enter an apikey is present in the test ui of the browser, but the operations don't care what I enter; they run anyway. I get the feeling there is something else I need to do, and this comment alludes to the same:

```
//These only define the schemes and need to be coupled with a corresponding "security" property
// at the document or operation level to indicate which schemes are required for an operation. To do this,
// you'll need to implement a custom IDocumentFilter and/or IOperationFilter to set these properties
// according to your specific authorization implementation
```

But I'm not really sure what I have to do next from this/how it is intended to work in the context of Swashbuckle. There doesn't seem to be any `[SwaggerXxx]` annotation that is obviously "If you add this annotation the operation will only work if the apikey is correct"

How do I mark my operation/controller method as "needs a valid api key" ?

Comment: That has nothing to do with swagger. Your webapi needs an authentication and an authorization middleware. Then you can use Policy or Rolebased Authorization on controllers, endpoints or as a global Filter for all calls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @Mono so are you saying that this config option merely tells swagger "every time you describe this service, also mention that the remote user has to send a header of  ApiKey with a relevant value" - it's nothing to do with actually implementing the security, it's purely about documenting the service because Swashbuckle cannot inspect/reflect the methods and work out what kid of auth must be passed in order for the auth filter to pass and call the action? And that even document/operation filters don't implement any security, they just describe how to generate the documentation of the security

Comment: It certainly can use reflection to check your controllers for Authorize Attributes for example: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#add-security-definitions-and-requirements
But you have to secure your rest api yourself anyway. Even if you could bring swagger to respond with 401/403, your rest api is still available just in the browser without using swagger. Swagger is meant to describe (and test) your api for external developers basically. It is like a documentation tool

Answer (score 0):

Per the steer from Mono's comments and some other web sources, I now understand that this setup in Swashbuckle doesn't add api key based auth to the project, it simply causes Swashbuckle/Swagger to emit json describing the service, that includes advice to the effect that the service requires an Api Key header with a suitable value (whether it's true or not, and in my case as there was no auth middle layer, it was not true)

I made it true by creating the following class:

```
    class AuthorizeByApiKeyAttribute : Attribute, System.Web.Http.Filters.IAuthenticationFilter
    {

        public bool AllowMultiple => false;

        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("apikey", out var e) && e.Contains("KEY HERE"))
                context.Principal = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity("Negotiate"));
            else
                context.ErrorResult = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) as IHttpActionResult;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

And then decorating the things I wanted to secure, with `[Authorize]` and `[AuthorizeByApiKey]`